# No muestra robot al iniciar job uipath orchestrator

Tags: uipath

Estoy intentando iniciar un job desde el Orchestrator de UiPath, pero al momento de seleccionar el proceso, no me despliega el robot creado para este.

Acá asigno el robot a un entorno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego desde start Job, busco el robot, pero no lo despliega en la lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la premisa que el robot se encuentra disponible y comparte ambiente con la automatización.

[image: Robot en Estado disponible y Activo]

Lo que debe tener en cuenta es que para lanzar ejecuciones desde el orquestador, sólo puede asignar Robots de tipo Desatendido (Unattended) o No Productivo (NonProduction).

[image: Tipo de robot Unattended o NonProduction]

Si en su caso, su robot es, por ejemplo, de tipo Studio, por eso no le aparecerá en la ventana de asignación.
Debe modificar el tipo de robot (De acuerdo a las posibilidades de su licencia) :

1. Robots
2. Edit
3. Y escoger Type: **NonProduction** o **Unattended**

Después de eso, puede volver a validar la asignación.

> Referencias
>
> - [Docs UiPath Robot Types](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/about-robots#robot-types)
> - [UiPath Forum - UiPath Robot](https://forum.uipath.com/t/uipath-robot-attended-unattended-non-production-development/168274)
> - [UiPath Forum - Studio scheduling will be disabled](https://forum.uipath.com/t/studio-scheduling-will-be-disabled-thoughts-pending-jobs/200090)